# websocket, how to not allow cross domain access?

Tags: websocket, cross-domain

Since the Origin does not work in the case of non-browser clients: non-browser clients can connect to a Websocket server with a fake origin. Non browser clients thereby can do requests that a programmer want through a program. How to stop this? I want that only my script hosted on my domain can connect to my websocket server. This page offers a “ticket”-based authentication system: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websocket-security

However, it looks like it does not solve this problem because any non-browser clients from anywhere can have a ticket also.

I want that only my script hosted on my domain can connect to my websocket server.

Please tell me how to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: This is impossible. Even if you did somehow manage to prevent all "non-browser" clients from accessing your WebSocket, those clients could simply launch a headless Chrome instance, navigate it to your site, then do whatever they want with the resulting WebSocket connection.